# Set end time of first row as start time of next row

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datatable

I have table with data like:

```
Id | Start         | End          | Used
----------------------------------------
1  | 27-04-17 2:00 |27-04-17 0:00 | 1:30
---------------------------------------
2  | 27-04-17 2:00 |27-04-17 0:00 | 23:00
---------------------------------------
3  | 27-04-17 2:00 |27-04-17 0:00 | 1:00
---------------------------------------
4  | 28-04-17 2:00 |28-04-17 0:00 | 0:30 
---------------------------------------
5  | 30-04-17 2:00 |30-04-17 0:00 | 3:30
---------------------------------------
```

I want to set it like

```
Id | Start         | End          | Used
----------------------------------------
1  | 27-04-17 2:00 |27-04-17 3:30 | 1:30
---------------------------------------
2  | 27-04-17 3:30 |28-04-17 2:30 | 23:00
---------------------------------------
3  | 28-04-17 2:30 |28-04-17 3:30 | 1:00
---------------------------------------
4  | 28-04-17 3:30 |28-04-17 4:00 | 0:30 
---------------------------------------
5  | 30-04-17 2:00 |30-04-17 4:30 | 2:30
---------------------------------------
```

I want to set End time of previous id as Start time of next id, where Start time of first id is set by user.
End time is just sum of Start time and Used Time I am using vb.net data table and SQL server for database. 
To set value in first row I am using SQL function DATEADD(), through which two hours are added and same function for adding time in end date. 
I want to copy my End date of previous row in next row, so that whole calculation works properly.
Can I do it through SQL Only? or I will need a function to do it in Vb.net Data table from where it will be used for reports. 
Note: Id sequence can be changed
 Thanks for help.

Comment: If you have a _database_ table like this you can just run an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Sorry I can't do that since record is for display purpose, permanent changes can't be made. It will also affect if sequence gets changed.

Comment: This is at it stands too broad. You need to show what _you_ have already tried. Do you want this doing on the database, or within VB.NET? Please see [ask].

Comment: @Bugs: This data is for report purpose, so it can be done in either way in vb or with database query (without updating database)

Comment: In all of your examples is just a matter of adding Used to Start. Why don't you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below recursive CTE logic will give you the desired output.

```
    create table #tmp
(
ID int,
starttime datetime2,
endtime datetime2,
used varchar(5)
)
insert into #tmp values 
(1,'17-Apr-2017 2:00','17-Apr-2017','1:30'),
(2,'17-Apr-2017 2:00','17-Apr-2017','2:00'),
(3,'17-Apr-2017 2:00','17-Apr-2017','1:00'),
(4,'17-Apr-2017 2:00','17-Apr-2017','0:30'),
(5,'28-Apr-2017 2:00','28-Apr-2017','3:30')

;with CTE as (
select ID,starttime,endtime,used,levels FROM
(select row_number() over (partition by cast(starttime as date) order by starttime) RID,ID,starttime,dateadd(hour,cast(substring(used,1,charindex(':',used)-1) as int),dateadd(mi,cast(right(used,2) as int),starttime))
endtime,used,0 levels
from #tmp ) T
where RID=1
union all
select T.ID,C.endtime,dateadd(hour,cast(substring(T.used,1,charindex(':',T.used)-1) as int),dateadd(mi,cast(right(T.used,2) as int),C.endtime))
endtime,T.used,C.levels+1
from CTE C inner join #tmp T on T.ID=C.ID+1
where datediff(d,C.starttime,T.starttime)=0
)

select ID,StartTime,EndTime,Used from CTE order by ID

drop table #tmp
```

Comment: You saved my day :)

Comment: Sorry, it is not working in few. Like if id 5 start on 28 april, due to CTE  start date is shifted back to 17 which is prior end date.

Comment: If I understood your concern then the edited answer should work. Tweaked the query little to consider different dates.

Comment: Yes that's I need need.. :)

Comment: Can I set Start time for id 1 through any variable also?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @ Rajesh try this data it is missing id 4 
(1,'17-Apr-2017 0:00','17-Apr-2017','1:30'),
(2,'17-Apr-2017 0:00','17-Apr-2017','23:00'),
(3,'17-Apr-2017 0:00','17-Apr-2017','1:00'),
(4,'17-Apr-2017 0:00','17-Apr-2017','10:30'),
(5,'28-Apr-2017 0:00','28-Apr-2017','3:30')

Comment: Depending on the date range you have to modify the where clause -where datediff(d,C.starttime,T.starttime)<=1. This will work if you crossing by 1 day. You can increase as per your requirement.